# sscanf format c++

Tags: c++, scanf

I have a sscanf statement as

```
sscanf (fieldname, "%s_%d", name, id);
```

I am giving input as frog_461 but it displays name as "frog_461" and 0 for id. Can you please suggest the correct way to give input to make this statement work? Like in the above example how should I give my input so that name="frog" and id=461. Thanks.

---

I appreciate all your input. Currently I cannot modify the code, therefore I am not trying to find an alternate way of getting it to work. I am just checking if this code was working earlier and if yes then what input the user must have given to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The answers given so far highlighting `sscanf`'s limitations are wrong! There is a correct way to do this with sscanf:

```
sscanf(fieldname, "%[^_]_%d", name, &id);
```

The `%[^_]` means to read until an underscore character is encountered. See the entry for `[` in the [man page for scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Also, notice the ampersand in front of `id` it is necessary to pass a pointer to `id`, in order to change it because of C's pass by value semantics.

By the way, this is really a C question and not a C++ one, so you should have probably tagged it as such. If you are using C++, there are much better options than `sscanf` for parsing.

Comment: It's a C99 feature, VS doesn't do C99

Comment: I appreciate your answers..actually this is an existing code and the person left the company :) How does the expression(%s_%d) expect as input to split as name and id. This has been in use for many years and I am not sure if anyone has used this option. Assuming this was working earlier, what kind of input did the users give to split correctly. Thanks,

Comment: @crashmstr, VC++ 2010 definitely supports this, from the help for "scanf width specification": To read strings not delimited by whitespace characters, a set of characters in brackets ( [ ]) can be substituted for the s (string) type character. The set of characters in brackets is referred to as a control string. The corresponding input field is read up to the first character that does not appear in the control string. If the first character in the set is a caret ( ^), the effect is reversed: The input field is read up to the first character that does appear in the rest of the character set.

Comment: Well, I see it in the help now. But before that, I made a sample c program and it is not working with your example.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` reads until it encounters whitespace, it doesn't know to stop at the underscore. One way to do this would be to search for the underscore yourself with `strchr`. Then you know where the first part of the string ends, and the number can be read with `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the poster knows that the "identifier" part of his token is only with (English lower-cases) letters, then he could try

```
char name[32];
memset (name, 0, sizeof(name));
if (sscanf(fieldname, "%31[a-z]_%d", name, num)>=2) {
   /* do something */
} else {
   /* bad fieldname */
}
```

Be careful with `sscanf` for C strings (i.e. char arrays) about string buffer overflow; always give a maximal size.

Answer (score -1):

scanf isn't a general regex parser it only handles whitespace.

You need to split the input string using strtok() or similar, or if you know the format just replace _ with " "